# how to convert a table into a dataframe in r?

Tags: r, dataframe

Suppose, I have a data set as follows:

```
State <- c("CA", "WI", "TX", "MS", "NY", "KT", "UT", "CO", "PA", "SC")
Pov_rt <- c(25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 10, 15, 25, 40)


df <- data. Frame(State, Pov_rt)
```

I have created a new column

```
df[["pov_level"]] <- cut(
  df$Pov_rt, 
  breaks = c(-Inf, 10, 20, 30, 40, Inf),
  labels = c(
    "Very Low Poverty (<10%)",
    "Low Poverty (10-20%)",
    "Medium Poverty (20-30%)",
    "High Poverty (30-40%)",
    "Very High Poverty (>40%)"
  )
)
```

I want to, further, get a table

```
table(df$pov_level, df$State)
                          
                           CA CO KT MS NY PA SC TX UT WI
  Very Low Poverty (<10%)   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0
  Low Poverty (10-20%)      0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  Medium Poverty (20-30%)   1  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  1
  High Poverty (30-40%)     0  0  0  1  0  0  1  1  0  0
  Very High Poverty (>40%)  0  0  1  0  1  0  0  0  0  0
```

If I want to convert this table as a dataframe, I go about it as

```
x <- data.frame(unclass(table(df$pov_level, df$State)))
```

instead of `x <- as.data.frame(table(df$pov_level, df$State))` since this gives me a dataframe of an ungrouped list.

But using the first one has an issue where sometimes I'd need to `mutate` the rownames as a new column.

I was wondering if there is a better way of doing this.

Much thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We could use `as.data.frame.matrix`

```
df2 <- as.data.frame.matrix(table(df$pov_level, df$State))
```

-output

```
> df2
                         CA CO KT MS NY PA SC TX UT WI
Very Low Poverty (<10%)   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0
Low Poverty (10-20%)      0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
Medium Poverty (20-30%)   1  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  1
High Poverty (30-40%)     0  0  0  1  0  0  1  1  0  0
Very High Poverty (>40%)  0  0  1  0  1  0  0  0  0  0
> str(df2)
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  10 variables:
 $ CA: int  0 0 1 0 0
 $ CO: int  0 1 0 0 0
 $ KT: int  0 0 0 0 1
 $ MS: int  0 0 0 1 0
 $ NY: int  0 0 0 0 1
 $ PA: int  0 0 1 0 0
 $ SC: int  0 0 0 1 0
 $ TX: int  0 0 0 1 0
 $ UT: int  1 0 0 0 0
 $ WI: int  0 0 1 0 0
```

Column can be created from rownames with `rownames_to_column` (`tibble`)

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
df2 %>%
  rownames_to_column("pov_levels")
                pov_levels CA CO KT MS NY PA SC TX UT WI
1  Very Low Poverty (<10%)  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0
2     Low Poverty (10-20%)  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
3  Medium Poverty (20-30%)  1  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  1
4    High Poverty (30-40%)  0  0  0  1  0  0  1  1  0  0
5 Very High Poverty (>40%)  0  0  1  0  1  0  0  0  0  0
```

---

Or if we want to use `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyr)
pivot_wider(df, names_from = State, values_from = Pov_rt,
     values_fn = length, values_fill = 0)
# A tibble: 5 × 11
  pov_level                   CA    WI    TX    MS    NY    KT    UT    CO    PA    SC
  <fct>                    <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1 Medium Poverty (20-30%)      1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0
2 High Poverty (30-40%)        0     0     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     1
3 Very High Poverty (>40%)     0     0     0     0     1     1     0     0     0     0
4 Very Low Poverty (<10%)      0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0
5 Low Poverty (10-20%)         0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0
```

---

Or more directly with `tabyl`

```
library(janitor)
df %>%
   tabyl(pov_level, State)
                pov_level CA CO KT MS NY PA SC TX UT WI
  Very Low Poverty (<10%)  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0
     Low Poverty (10-20%)  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  Medium Poverty (20-30%)  1  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  1
    High Poverty (30-40%)  0  0  0  1  0  0  1  1  0  0
 Very High Poverty (>40%)  0  0  1  0  1  0  0  0  0  0
```

Comment: Thanks! Here, again, I would need to use the mutate function if I were to have a column for pov_levels.

Comment: @Tathagato you can use `library(tibble);as.data.frame.matrix(table(df$pov_level, df$State)) %>% rownames_to_column("pov_levels")`

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative approach with `model.matrix`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  cbind(model.matrix(~ State + 0, .) == 1) %>% 
  mutate(across(-c(1:3), ~as.integer(.)))
```

```
   State Pov_rt                pov_level StateCA StateCO StateKT StateMS StateNY StatePA StateSC StateTX StateUT StateWI
1     CA     25  Medium Poverty (20-30%)       1       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
2     WI     30  Medium Poverty (20-30%)       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       1
3     TX     35    High Poverty (30-40%)       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       1       0       0
4     MS     40    High Poverty (30-40%)       0       0       0       1       0       0       0       0       0       0
5     NY     45 Very High Poverty (>40%)       0       0       0       0       1       0       0       0       0       0
6     KT     50 Very High Poverty (>40%)       0       0       1       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
7     UT     10  Very Low Poverty (<10%)       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       1       0
8     CO     15     Low Poverty (10-20%)       0       1       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
9     PA     25  Medium Poverty (20-30%)       0       0       0       0       0       1       0       0       0       0
10    SC     40    High Poverty (30-40%)       0       0       0       0       0       0       1       0       0       0
```